# Why doesn't my <a href> links work? My testing link works opening up a Testing.php file but the others just seem to refresh the Index.php

Tags: php, html, href

1. This is my Index.php file which won't get me to any other page

   ```
   <?php
       session_start();
       include_once 'dbconnect.php';
       //Connecting to the database

           if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
               header("Location: Login.php");
               }
           //If the user is not logged in, this code will redirect them to the Login page

           $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserID=".$_SESSION['user']);
           $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
           /*This is finding all the data based on the User's User ID.
            This is very safe as it will only find the data relevant to the User that is logged in */
   ?>
   ```

   Welcome -

   ```
   <h1>Welcome <?php echo $userRow['Username']; ?> to our website</h1>
   <!-- This here is doing the same thing as before -->
   <a href="Logout.php?logout"> Log Out</a> | <a href="MySubjects.php"> My Subjects</a> |
   <a href = "NewSubject.php"> Add a new subject</a>

   <a href = "Test.php"> Testing</a>
   ```

2.This is my NewSubject.php file. Both this and MySubjects.php are similar to each other

```
    <?php
    require_once('Dbconnect.php');
    //Connecting to the database

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
            header("Location: Login.php");
        }

    //User is being redirected to the login page if they are not logged in.

    else{
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE UserID=".$_SESSION['user']);
    $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
    }
    //This is fetching the data based on the Session Variable UserID
    ?>

</head>
<title> Add a new subject</title>

<body>

    <form method = "Post">

        <select name = SubjectName>
            <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
            <option value="FurtherMaths">Further Maths</option>
            <option value="EnglishLanguage">English Language</option>
            <option value="EnglishLiterature">Engliash Literature</option>
        </select>

    </form>

    <a href="Logout.php?logout"> Log Out</a> | <a href="My Subjects.php"> My Subjects</a> |
    <a href = "NewSubject.php"> Add a new subject</a>

</body>
```

3. Sorry if this is obvious or something but I am very new to PHP and am doing this as a personal project with a friend. I think it's a problem with the PHP code because my test.php file link works fine which only has this code within html and body tags:

THIS IS A TEST!

Comment: Suggested reading: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is your file structure ? and what is `Logout.php?logout` ? GET request parameters should be `key=value` pairs

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear. The result of this should be that when the <a href> link is clicked upon, the pages MySubjects.php and NewSubject.php should be opened. Instead of this happening, the site simply reloads Index.php. However, when I removed the PHP code and just added HTML text (see my Test.php), the link does seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a lot of research and I have found the answer to what is going wrong in my code. The problem is that at the start of each of my page I have forgotten to write the following: `session_start();`

this means, everytime I try to open the link, it doesn't follow the `if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))`
because it doesn't exist in that page (as there is no session variable set).

Therefore, when I wrote session_start();, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably causing your redirection:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
     header("Location: Login.php");
}
```

In this case, Login.php is causing a redirect to Index.php despite being logged in.

You need to setup some kind of Session controller (could be simply Sessions.php) where you perform the session checks to make sure the current user is logged in, then set the `$_SESSION['user']` there or redirect to Login.php.

Then you need to require that file in all of your files that rely on it.

---

There are tutorials on Cookie/Session control out there I would personally just search around for it.

Comment: I thought this was just code to redirect the user if they are not logged in. I am assuming that because the user is logged in, they should still be able to access this page without the redirection but I guess that is not true? I need to be making cookies to remember the user is logged in or something?

Comment: Well, are you setting `$_SESSION['user']` anywhere before that if condition?

Comment: Yes (I think). On my Login.php, the code I have is 
$_SESSION['user'] = $row['UserID'];
after an If statement to make sure that the password entered matches the UserName

Comment: Also I don't think my require_once('Dbconnect.php); is at fault here as this is how I've spelt it in my file directory (because I just find it easier to write and see with a capital :3 )

Comment: I see, yea that would have caused issues. 

Does your Login.php redirect to Index.php?

Comment: Yes it does:
 if($row['Password'] == md5($Password)){
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $row['UserID'];
                    header("Location: Index.php");
                   }

Comment: Ok, that is your issue then. `$_SESSION['user']` is ONLY set in Login.php, and thus it will always redirect to Index.php

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Do I therefore need to be continuously defining $_SESSION['user'] in all my pages or something? And if so, how?

Comment: Thanks! I will do that soon (I don't have time to check right now) but I think it will work because the logic seems correct. This was my first ever question on StackOverflow so thanks a billion! Very useful